# Disable received emails in confidential mode

Tags: email, gmail, automation

In Gmail, there are contacts of myn sending to me emails in confidential mode, which make it harder for me to manage in automation.

Is there an option to make all emails I recieve as unconfidential?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be. You probably should explain to the people who are sending this to you that it makes it more difficult to manage your mail, and that you would prefer not to receive mail in this way. Note that if this is for employer-related mail, you may not have a choice about dealing with confidential email; company policy may require that confidential mode be used in at least some cases.

Comment: This is a private Gmail. I cannot control my contacts. Is there an option to do any automation - mayb create new email with the condifential email text in it?

Comment: The mechanisms that Google has implemented for confidential email _specifically_ make it essentially impossible to automate access - if you are not using a GMail client (none of which can be automated), you _will_ have to receive a passcode and enter it to access the confidential message.

Comment: See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7674059

Comment: Yes i'm aware, but maybe someone thought on a workaround. For example, this ,https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/email_forwarder/458006161590, takes all gmails into a sheet and than does email sending. Do you think any chance stuff like that might work?

Comment: What kind of automation are we even talking about? What’s your e-mail client?

Comment: My email clients is gmail. Im using gmail addons and filters for automations

Comment: What is "confidential mode"? Is it something internal to Gmail? In SMTP standards, there's no such thing as "confidential mode". Using private, nonstandard features is highly discouraged. Maybe you can explain to your contants that what they're doing is **nonstandard** and **unsupported**.